# Devexpress Report Minus On the Right

Tags: devexpress

In a DevExpress Report, I need to show negative numbers with the minus sign on the right rather than left in Table Cells.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I have searched the DevExpress forum and userguide, but cannot see anything useful. There is also nothing in the Table Cell's Properties.

Currently I am using the following 'Format String':

```
{0:#,#.00}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) article just try this format:

```
{0:#,#.00;#,#.00-}
```

Comment: That solved the issue for some of the numbers, but I ended up with some odd number layouts in the larger numbers. Thanks for the help!